# New lights installed but won’t work

Tags: wiring, led

My son installed some lights in my living room and tapped into an outlet to run the wires.  We keep having issues with the lights sometimes working but mostly not.  It doesn’t flip the breaker so it can’t be a surge. The outlet we tapped into and an adjacent one are not working as well. I feel that we have over checked the wires and connections but it still keeps happening! Can anyone help us figure it out? Thanks in advance!

[image] [image]

1st photo is the outlet we tapped into.  We ended up taking the outlet out because there were wires stuck in the back (as one commenter mentioned)

2nd photo is the switch. He wrapped electrical tape around it for security I suppose.

Comment: Can you turn off the breaker and pull out the receptacles (without disconnecting any wires) and take pictures showing all the wires/connections and upload the pictures?

Comment: Have your son re-check all the connections.

Comment: I’m trying to add pics but this website is being goofy on my phone

Comment: Classical loose connection. Are any of the wires just poked into holes in the back of the outlets, rather than being clamped by screws? Those connections are highly prone to failing. Wire nuts can also be tricky to get solidly connected to all wires if you're not used to them. Please [edit] to provide the pictures requested. Should be a "sun and mountains" icon at the top of the edit box - I dunno if phone is any different, I come here via computer. Got one up, I see - I'd **crank** that nut on the whites **a lot harder** than it appears to be - bare wire should not be showing out the bottom.

Comment: The white wire is overtwisted near the insulation and prone to stress fracture. Black has a smaller twist angle and appears OK. But both ought to be redone straight and twisted inside inside cap without conductor exposed.

Comment: Feel free to strip a little more sheath off that cable. The sheath only *needs* <10mm past the cable clamp, plus whatever distance you want for writing on it.  Also, better sockets can take 4 wires per side via screw-and-clamp, so that might be an easy way to get a socket without pigtailing.